# Angular 7 Material dialog config data inject name conflict

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to pass some data when opening a material dialog panel. The following example is what I learned from [here](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component-)

#### Sharing data with the Dialog component.

If you want to share data with your dialog, you can use the data option to pass information to the dialog component.

```
let dialogRef = dialog.open(YourDialog, {
  data: { name: 'austin' },
});
```

To access the data in your dialog component, you have to use the MAT_DIALOG_DATA injection token:

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'your-dialog',
  template: 'passed in {{ data.name }}',
})
export class YourDialog {
  data: any[] = []; // existing code, conflict
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }
}
```

Now the problem is in the dialog component, there has been already a variable `data` defined and used. And the variable name `data` being passed into the dialog as config is dictated by Angular Material Dialog. So it causes a naming conflict. I could change the existing `data` variable to something else to give way to the Angular injected `data`, but  is there a way to change the injected `data` to be something else? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to keep the same variable names.

```
constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public anyOtherNameHereIsOk: any) { }
```

Why this works is that the parameter is already being decorated with `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)` so the actual name of the parameter does not matter. Use a name that works best given the type of data and how it is used (and any other naming rules you might be accustomed to).

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-31hfog), see class `DialogDataExampleDialog`

Comment: Thanks! It works. I thought the data in the constructor parameter is corresponding to the data in the open method. I wonder how the dialog constructor knows that `anyOtherNameHereIsOk` is corresponding to the data from the open method call, because in the open method call, actually we passed in another field called `panelClass` along with `data`.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen - the 2nd parameter of `MatDialog.open` expects a type with a member named `data`. Whatever you assign there is passed to the dialog's constructor argument that is decorated with `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)` and the argument's name can be anything you want it to be.